# Do Jewish historians consider the destruction of Jerusalem in 70 CE on par with the Shoah/Holocaust?

Tags: history, holocaust-shoah

I'm trying to get a sense for how devastating it was to Jews at the time relative to the Shoah of modern times.

Comment: Consider the fact that it's still being mourned 2000 years later.

Comment: Consider the fact that the entire basis of the "Jewish religion" at that time was being destroyed and we could have fallen apart completely.

Comment: @sabbahillel I’m not disagreeing with your comment. Only noting that the Shoah is compared to the type of destruction from Purim. Worse, it was more successful. 2nd Temple destruction was aimed at the stones primarily. The people and culture were preserved for the most part. It doesn’t make light of the enormous loss, but remember the Kruvim on top of the Ark were embracing. I’ve heard of no such allegory with the Shoah.

Comment: This seems primarily opinion based. How do we quantify if they were similarly devastating

Comment: @DoubleAA, luckily the asker asked not for us to quantify that but whether historians have done so. I'm not an historian; perhaps they have some way of doing so; if not, not, but I don't see how this is seeking answerers' opinions.

Comment: It's not clear that this question is about Judaism *per se*, as opposed to Jews' experiences, and it's therefore unclear that it's [on-topic](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If this question is indeed about Judaism, could you please [edit] to flesh out the question body to clarify precisely what Judaism information you're seeking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Jewish Virtual Library** in the article entitled 'Ancient Jewish History: The Great Revolt (66-70 CE)' says:' . . . the Great Revolt of 66-70, followed some sixty years later by the Bar Kokhba revolt, were the greatest calamities in Jewish history prior to the Holocaust. In addition to the more than one million Jews killed, these failed rebellions led to the total loss of Jewish political authority in Israel until 1948.' ([The Great Revolt (66 - 70 CE) - Jewish Virtual Library](http://The%20Great%20Revolt%20(66%20-%2070%20CE)%20-%20Jewish%20Virtual%20Library))

*The Gospel of Mark* 13:19 reports that Jesus predicted that the days leading up to the destruction of the Temple would be 'days of distress unequaled from the beginning, when God created the world, until now—and never to be equaled again.' But in actual fact the Holocaust or Shoah surpassed the destruction of Jewish lives in those days manifold.